# STS 3.6.4 on Mac OS X Crashes on Launch

Tags: java, spring, macos

I have a fresh download of spring-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.4.2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz & JDK 8u45 on either Mac OS X 10.9.5 or 10.10.3 that crashes after launch.  STS loads, asks me where to create a workspace, the interface loads, then crashes about 15 seconds later.

Due to IT Security policies, I have to use Java 8, so downgrading the JDK to a lower version is not an option.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshot/fix this issue?

Note, I'm a System Admin preparing the package for deployment, not a developer.  I don't have any previous workspaces or old versions of the software installed on my machines.

Thanks!

Comment: Do the crash logs help shed some light on the issue?  Try looking in .metadata/.log under the workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually let it load your previous workspace, for example from STS 3.6.2 or something? If so, please make sure that you create a new workspace and then give it a shot.

I have been using STS 3.6.2. But after I saw your post, I decided to give it a tried. Downloaded it, unarchived it and ran it.It has been running for good 5-10 mins so far. So, I don't believe anything is wrong with the pack.

OS: MacOSX 10.10.3

Comment: I should have mentioned in the original post, now edited, that I'm not a developer, just a System Admin preparing the package for user deployment, so I don't have any previous workspaces to load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why this fixed it, but if I install the JDK 7 update 79 and then install JDK 8 update 45 everything runs.  I haven't done any real deep dives to see what parts 7u79, if any are being left behind after 8u45 gets installed, but it's working.